# How to prevent /etc/resolv.conf from getting overwritten after reboot in Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: networking, dns, ubuntu-11.10, dhcp

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and I manually configure DNS servers in /etc/resolv.conf but it gets somehow overwritten after I reboot. How can I prevent this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figure that the NetworkManager is overwriting the /etc/resolv.conf file. In my case it was the order in which my DNS servers were listed was something I wanted to change. You can do that through the NetworkManager by editing your connection IP4V settings.

Answer (score 14):

As you can read in the header of resolv.conf :

```
Dynamic resolv.conf file for glibc resolver generated by resolvconf
```

So, the resolv.conf is generated, if you want to keep the resolvconf configuration after reboot, you will have to edit /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base. In that file, put in your info as you would in resolv.conf.

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Then regenerate resolv.conf with resolvconf:

```
sudo resolvconf -u
```

Answer (score 6):

After reading other answers, I still needed something different for the following reasons:

- I'm not using `resolvconf`, just plain `/etc/resolv.conf`.
- Using `chattr +i` to lock down `resolv.conf` seems too hacky. I need Puppet to be free to make changes when necessary.

The [best solution](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/dhclient-etcresolvconf-hooks/) I found overrides the default behavior of `dhclient` using its documented hooks.

Create a new file at `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/nodnsupdate` with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
make_resolv_conf() {
    :
}
```

Then make the file executable:

```
chmod +x /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/nodnsupdate
```

Now when dhclient runs -- either on reboot or when you manually run `sudo ifdown -a ; sudo ifup -a` -- it loads this script `nodnsupdate`. This script overrides an internal function called `make_resolv_conf()` that would normally overwrite `resolv.conf` and instead does nothing.

This worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: If you use 'chattr +i', some VPN SW (I.E.: pulse secure) could have problems when they try to set DNS to point to specific server addresses (I.E.: corporate ones).

Answer (score 1):

NetworkManager can be configured to use manually entered IPv4 configuration, or get from DHCP IP/netmask/router only - in such a case it should not change /etc/resolv.conf

However, one may want have his own settings in the /etc/resolv.conf - like nameserver or domain to search; I just need a domain and I did by adding a file /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99my_fix containing:

`#!/bin/bash
rc=/etc/resolv.conf; le="search my.domain"
grep -q domain $rc && ! grep -q "$le" $rc && echo "$le" >> $rc`

Of course I chmod-ed +x it. The NetworkManager invokes it after setting the /etc/resolv.conf and my script fixes it if nesessary; the first grep detects that network is up, the second that the fix was not applied - they both are necessary for the fix to be applied.

Answer (score 0):

You have DHCP client doing this. Follow these [instructions](http://raamdev.com/2009/configuring-static-dns-with-dhcp-on-debianubuntu/) to override that.

Comment: I tried the solution you linked to, but it does not work. It looks like the Network Manager is doing this as the first line in /etc/resolv.conf reads : "# Generated by NetworkManager". Generally, Is there a way to know the programs editing /etc/resolv.conf?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following line :
    chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf

to undo use :
    chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf

Let me know if it worked...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I edited my `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf' file by adding domain-name and domain-name-servers

`supersede domain-name "local.com";
supersede domain-name-servers 192.168.56.103;`

192.168.56.103 is my vm running bind9 and my domain name is local.com

and I have removed the same from `request` section as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the network interfaces for your server instance is controlled by DHCP, the dhclient program will overwrite your /etc/resolv.conf file whenever the networking service is restarted.

You can fix the issue by editing the "/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf" file and adding supersede statements for **domain-name**, **domain-search** and **domain-name-servers** as follows:

```
supersede domain-name "mydomain.com";
supersede domain-search "mydomain.com"
supersede domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;
```

In this particular case the name server is located at "8.8.8.8" and the domain name is "mydomain.com". Substitute your particular information.

Note that each line is terminated by a semi-colon and the domain name is enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: I have a related question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1453982/ubuntu-22-04-1-nameservers-keep-getting-overwritten